# UITableViewController and NSFetchedResultsController Editing Issues

Tags: ios, core-data

In my app, I manage a library of music files using CoreData as the backing store. Works pretty well. I also use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to bind the data to a table view for display, which is also all fine and dandy. The issue arises when I try to enable editing on the table view.

As usual, I return `YES` from `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` to allow rows to be editied, enabling the swipe to delete UI. That works nicely and shows up right. However, after deleting files and whatnot, the `UITableView` begins having some strange rendering issues:

[image: uitableview issues]

I don't send any messages to the tableview to explicitly request UI updates, since the fetched results controller notifies my `UITableViewController` subclass of this, which then sends the appropriate messages:

```
/**
 * Handler for changing an entire section at once
 */
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Handler for changing a single object, usually a row.
 */
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Called when the fetched results controller begins sending update messages.
 */
- (void) controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *) controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

/**
 * Called when the fetched results controller finishes sending updates.
 */
- (void) controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *) controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

After reading the docs, I'm pretty sure all I need to do is delete the object from the context, which happens like this:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {            
        // perform on the object context's background queue
        [[SQUPersistence sharedInstance].managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            [[SQUPersistence sharedInstance].managedObjectContext deleteObject:[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

            // Save database
            [[SQUPersistence sharedInstance] save:nil];
        }];
    }
}
```

Eventually, the UI enters a strange state as seen above and the table gets out of sync with the backing store, and no animations are performed. Am I doing this entire deletion thing wrong, or have I encountered a bug with Apple's classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is threading issue. If you're deleting on the background queue, but referencing the object from the main queue, `[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]`, I am sure that will cause problems.

Right off, I would confirm by trying:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {  
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = _fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext;          
        [context deleteObject:[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        // Save database (You do not have to do this here)
        [context save:nil];
    }
}
```

If you do  not have issues doing it this way, I'd suggest leaving it. There is likely little benefit in deleting a single object in the background. Where you might hang would be the save operation, which you don't actually need to do here. You can leave the save till user exits or some other point at which any lag would be masked by the UI change.

Comment: This doesn't change the behaviour of the app—the object is of course still deleted, but the interface is not updated to reflect that. Could this be an issue arising from using custom filter predicates with the fetched results controller in some instances?

Comment: if you are just using a predicate in the fetch property of the NSFetchedResultsController, I would say no. If you are filtering the  results array, then yes, you will need to address that differently. You should show your table source methods.